# What is "reboatory"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Reading my latest Michael Innes story "Stop Press", I came across this in a passage concerning a train journey:-

> Timmy's voice and the rattle of the train's subterraneous plunge were alike drowned in an awful and bewildering clamour. A pandemonium of sound, latrant, mugient, **reboatory**, and beyond all words, reverberated between the walls of the tunnel.

I have managed to run down *latrant* and *mugient* but *reboatory* doesn't appear in any dictionary I have access to; DuckDuckGo reports no results.

Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: This appears to be a term unique to the writings of Michael Innes.  Presumably he reached for the most obscure term he could find -- "reboant", as discussed by sumelic -- and then made it even more obscure with a new suffix.

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly. 'Michael Innes' was actually J.I.M.Stewart, a very distinguished literary critic and English professor at Oxford; he wrote some 50 detective novels (very good novels, in fact) noted for their tongue-in-cheek use of obscure language and densely allusive dialogue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Although I also haven't been able to find a dictionary that lists this particular form, it seems fairly clear that *reboatory* is related to the words *[reboant](https://onelook.com/?w=reboant)* and *[reboation](https://onelook.com/?w=reboation&ls=a).*

The OED defines *reboant* as "Chiefly *literary* and *poet.* Resounding, reverberating; loudly echoing" and *reboation* as "A resounding echo; a reverberation," and says these come from Latin "*reboāre* to re-echo".

So "reboatory" presumably is a fancy way of saying "echoing". Since the word "reverberated" is used later in the sentence, you don't actually need to know what "reboatory" means to get the gist (which I assume is intentional, like the famous example where Shakespeare repeats the meaning of the polysyllabic "multitudinous seas incarnadine" with the easier-to-understand "making the green one red").

Using Google Books, I found one other use (that isn't just a mention or disccusion of Innes' use) in *[New Scientist](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZUwz_1Gyj-oC&pg=PA632&dq=%22reboatory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjStubB9fPaAhVX_oMKHQbvCx8Q6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22reboatory%22&f=false)* Vol 82 No 1215, Aug 21, 1980, but the context (a joke about there being an appropriate "-tory" adjective to describe each Tory cabinet member) doesn't make it particularly easy to understand what is meant:

> William Whitelaw is, naturally, reboatory.

(p. 632)

Comment: Thank you for this. From the OED entry, I had thought the word rare and unused since the 18th century.  Your citation about Willie White-law has shown me wrong.  I was taught that such a word should never have been brought into this world. It is the misbegotten offspring of a Greek stem (boao- βόαω =  I shout) and a Latin prefix (re-) and ending (-atory).  ‘Anaboastic’ would have been more linguistically consistent.  Ironically,  βοαω is connected with the word βους (pronounced ‘boose’, as in ‘loose’), which means an ox.  The Latin, ‘mugient’ is also the noise of cattle.

Comment: @Tuffy: I'm not sure if Latin *boo* is actually taken from Greek, or if it's just a cognate to the Greek word. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boo#Latin) says "From bōs +‎ -ō." and [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dboo) say "**kindr.** with Sanscr. gu and the Gr. βοάω" rather than something like "derived from the Greek βοάω".

Comment: Oops, you’re dead right.  What was I thinking?  Serves me right.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: In fact, now I check properly, as I should have in the first place, there is a perfectly good use in Virgil himself:  “reboant silvaeque et longus Olympus” - “the woods and mountain resound” (Georgics III 223).  But there is a good reason for the word.  He is describing the clashing horns of two bulls fighting over a female.  So just the right word!